# SQL Percent Error. Trouble with trying to use ABS()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the Percent error of two columns for each row.

Currently I tried

```
    UPDATE Weather
SET PercentError=ActualTemp - ForecastTemp / ActualTemp * 100
```

Which I know is in correct because when i do the calculations it doesn't match up with what the sql gives me. I then tried to use something along the lines of

```
    UPDATE Weather
SET PercentError=ABS (ActualTemp - ForecastTemp) / ActualTemp * 100
```

But when i do this I just get 0 for my Percent error. I used ABS because I know it works with an INT but wanted to see if it would work when subtracting two columns.

I have been looking up how to subtract two columns using abs but they just use ABS to turn their number into positive and never use it in the equation itself. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction on how to get this to work correctly?
*Using Microsoft sql server

Comment: Use floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Or cast it to a decimal

Comment: Try `ABS(x - y) * 100.0 / z`

Comment: What is the data-type of the columns you're working with? Be wary of implicit integer-float conversion.

Comment: It's probably because your data type is `INT`.  Anything less than 1 will return 0.

Comment: @MatBailie This worked thank you.

Comment: Also thank you to @TheImpaler

Comment: Hey, upvote us!

Comment: @TheImpaler I dont have above 15 rep yet :(, I tried. When it lets me choose the solution ill pick what you said though. Hopefully someone else will be able to use solution for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing integer calculations. Try floating point math:

```
UPDATE Weather
  SET PercentError=
    (100.0 * ABS (ActualTemp - ForecastTemp)) / ActualTemp
```

Note that I placed the 100 in front of the equation, and forced the multiplication before the division.

Answer (score 0):

How bout fixing the parentheses?

```
UPDATE Weather
    SET PercentError = (ActualTemp - ForecastTemp) * 100.0 / ActualTemp ;
```

The `100.0` ensures that the division is not integer division.

Negative numbers seem reasonable, but you can include `ABS()`:

```
UPDATE Weather
    SET PercentError = ABS(ActualTemp - ForecastTemp) * 100.0 / ActualTemp ;
```